Can I write a TypeScript interface describing an object that doesn't inherit from `Object`?
This is only a hypothetical question, i.e. it doesn't represent a real problem. It arose from writing an article about how classes work in JavaScript, expressing some weird consequences about their internals, which made me think, "I wonder if this weird usage of JavaScript can be expressed in TypeScript?"
When I create a class in JavaScript, by default it "inherits from" Object. I.e. the prototype of it's prototype will be Object's prototype.
So TypeScript assumes that these are all present on an object
class Foo {}

function x(y: Foo) {
  // Valid. `toString` doesn't exist on Foo, it exist on `Object`
  return y.toString();
}

Object itself doesn't inherit from anything, so it's prototype's prototype is null.
> Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.prototype)
null

But the prototype chain is mutable, which is how we would simulate inheritance before the class keyword was introduced, although that was for inserting a base class; not removing one. But I could break up with Object, by setting the prototype's prototype to null.
> const f = new Foo()
undefined
> f.toString()
'[object Object]'
> Object.setPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype, null)
[Object: null prototype] {}
> f.toString()
Uncaught TypeError: f.toString is not a function

Now Foo has no base class. Yet the TypeScript interface includes all properties of Object.
Can I correctly simulate this behaviour?
p.s. If you read this and think, "Hey, I could do that in ...", don't. Just don't.

This is ms/TS#1108. TS never intended to model such behavior (it’s apparently infrequent enough in real world code so as not to be a big problem for TS devs). There are clunky workarounds but it’s basically a missing feature. Does that fully address the question? If so I’ll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not what am I missing?

@jcalz The scenario is slightly different, but the problem is fundamentally the same, so I would say yes, it answers my question; this type of behaviour isn't supported ;) Which is also what I somewhat expected.

See microsoft/TypeScript#1108.
TypeScript cannot model such types.   It is indeed assumed by TypeScript that all object types (including auto-boxed primitives) inherit from Object.  This assumption, while technically false, works well enough in practice that TypeScript doesn't receive a lot of bug reports about this.  There's a feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#1108 asking to support null prototype objects, but it's been open for a long time and only acquired a few dozen upvotes, so it doesn't seem there's lots of demand for it.
As mentioned in the discussion there, the closest you can get to removing the Object.prototype methods from an object type in TypeScript is to narrow them to never:
type NotObject = Record<keyof Object, never>

function makeNotObject<T extends object>(obj: T) {
    const ret = Object.create(null!);
    Object.assign(ret, obj);
    return ret as T & NotObject;
}

const o = makeNotObject({ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 });
console.log(o.a.toFixed(2)) // "1.00"
o.toString(); // error!
//~~~~~~~~ <-- This expression is not callable. 

But TypeScript still treats this like a subtype of Object, which is the opposite of what you're talking about.

Note that even if null-prototype object types were supported, the particular example you show might not be, because TypeScript also doesn't model mutations of a type. You can narrow the type of an existing object, but not change it arbitrarily. So Object.setPrototypeOf()'s behavior on its input can't be represented.
There's a feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#22865 to allow such things, but this one seems to have even less community support.  For prototypes it's much better to just Object.create() an object with the desired prototype.
Playground link to code
